# Why is the electric field in a conductor zero at equilibrium

Tags: electric-fields, conductors

This question has already been asked, but it has many answers and comments and I thought it would be tidyer not to add another discussion to it. In this forum and in many others, I find the following explanation :

*"If the field was nonzero in the conductor, charged particles would move contradicting equilibrium."*

I would prefer it stated this way : *"If the field was nonzero at a point containing a charged particle, then the particle would move"*.

Which brings me to this. If the particles are still, then obviously the field is zero where they are located. But why would it be zero anywhere else ? Somewhere where there is no particle ?

If we imagine a metallic non-hollow sphere so small that it has only two free electrons. They would spread diametrically. The field would be zero only at the center. I'm assuming this thought to have something wrong about it, because even where the charges are, the field is nonzero. Maybe it helps reveal where I'm stuck ?

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned the answer, the field is zero where the charges are located. And charges are located *everywhere* inside the metal.

Comment: Why is that ? Aren't they hundreds of diameters apart ?